# What is the best way of generating unique id's in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I want to generate unique id's for insurances contracts, not sure which tool to use...

Comment: A short search on Google would have given you some answers

Comment: Unfortunately google returns this page https://www.google.ch/search?q=What+is+the+best+way+of+generating+unique+id%27s+in+Node.js%3F&oq=What+is+the+best+way+of+generating+unique+id%27s+in+Node.js

Comment: Google search: https://www.google.ch/search?q=unique+id+node+js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several options to create unique ids. The easiest would be just an increasing integer. However, I assume you will have some form of api and you probably don't want other people to be able to guess other persons unique ids. So I would go for uuid.v4 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

Install package

```bash
$ yarn add uuid
$ npm install uuid --save
```

Then in your code

```javascript
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4')
const uniqueInsuranceId = uuidv4()
```

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You should use uuid package.

**Features:**

Support for version 1, 4 and 5 UUIDs

Cross-platform

Uses cryptographically-strong random number APIs (when available)

Zero-dependency, small footprint (... but not this small)

[You can download from here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

Comment: I do like your answer. It helped me a lot. However I cannot up vote it :(.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid is probably one of the most commonly used unique id generators.